# How does map() in Streams works and how to work with it when the argument is a Collection

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I am working with Streams in Java 8. I need to implement a method in the Colegio class where it returns each note (Inscripcion.getNota()) from the list "inscriptionList" in the Curso class. Use filter() to know the notes of a Curso passed its "Name" (nombreCurso) by parameter. The method must be implemented using Streams. I don't understand how the map() method works using a List as an argument. Its possible something like this? (void notasDelCurso(nombreCurso))

In Colegio class:

```
public class Colegio {
    private List<Curso> cursos;

    //Constructor and getter omitted

public void notasDelCurso(String nombreCurso){
    cursos.stream()
          .filter(s -> s.getNombreCurso().equals(nombreCurso))
          .map(s -> s.getInscripcionList().stream()
                                          .map(j -> j.getNota()))
          .forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
}
```

Curso:

```
public class Curso {
    private String nombreCurso;
    private Integer cupo;
    private double notaAprobacion;
    private List<Inscripcion> inscripcionList;

   //Constructor and getter omitted
```

Inscripcion:

```
public class Inscripcion {
    private Alumno alumno;
    private Curso curso;
    private long nota;

    //Constructor and getter omitted
```

The output:
java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3@5fd0d5ae

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand how the map() method works using a List as an
>   argument

The `map` method transforms the current entity type to another type based on the `Function` you've provided.

> The output: java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3@5fd0d5ae

The output in your case for the same reason is printing the `Stream` to which you have mapped your initial entities.

---

When dealing with List or any other collection of entities, you want to flatten the collection and while transforming and for that you could use [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) operation from `Stream`. In the code you've shared, you can use it in the form of:

```
.flatMap(s -> s.getInscripcionList().stream()
                              .map(j -> j.getNota()))
```